# When is it most appropriate to post a preprint?

Tags: publications, open-access, preprint

I am a student who is very enthusiastic about open access and sharing research. When I worked with my former supervisor, we would write a paper and then post it to a preprint server (e.g., arXiv) *at the same time* as submitting it to a venue. My current supervisor, however, is of the mindset that we should post a preprint *after* receiving confirmation that the paper was accepted to some venue.

Is there a generally-accepted time to post a preprint?

Answer (score 2):

It makes the most sense to put it on arXiv when the preprint is complete (i.e. when xou submit it to a journal). (Some people even post to arXiv, wait a few days to maybe get interesting comments from other people (comments which improve the paper), and then submit it to a journal.) So the community can use your results before formal publication.

However, if for some reason or another, your supervisor does not want to do this, then their opinion trumps this argument.

Answer (score 1):

When the venues that you would like to submit to all *allow* preprints to be published.

If it is double blind, you probably can't. That would defeat the concept of double blind reviewing!

If you get rejected and would like to try another venue later, that one also matters... If you post the draft, it limits you choices where you can submit to.